# iOS: Garbage collection

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I know about iOS Automatic Reference Counting, which is compiler based feature. But, i have been going through many sites and confused with whether Garbage collection is also there or not on iOS program development? I know, ARC and GC is different each other. Some links says, GC is available for iOS and some links says GC is available only for Mac OS X development. But, i couldn't conclude saying whether the GC is there or not on iOS development? Please direct me the right path or link so that i can understand about it and try programming.

Thanks!

Comment: GC was available for OS X until May 1, 2015. It is now unavailable everywhere. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=02202015a

Answer (score 11, accepted):

iOS has no method of Garbage Collection.  Even so, Garbage Collection is entirely unnecessary (for all practical purposes) when ARC is used.  ARC works its magic at compile time to do the reference counting for you thereby making it unnecessary (and actually non-allowed) to use any other sort of memory management.

**Edit:**

To clarify, OS X does currently support garbage collection, but it is deprecated (unbeknown to me until a few minutes ago) as of OS X Mountain Lion.  iOS never has and never will support garbage collection.  Any advantages of garbage collection are moot when compared to those of ARC, and Apple has made the move to (forcefully) nudge us in the right direction.

Comment: Technically garbage collection has some advantages that automatic reference counting doesn't — most notably retain cycles aren't an issue (so, no need manually to worry about weak references versus strong references). But, yes, it's sufficiently unnecessary that it's never going to be implemented and ARC does essentially the same job.

Comment: Garbage collection has never been perfect in my experience, and relying on it has proved... problematic.

Comment: @Tommy Being able to break retain cycles isn't an inherit feature of Garbage Collectors. In fact, there are quite a few which can't deal with such things and you end up with a leak, even though there is a GC in place.

Comment: @JustSid fair point but nevertheless Apple's garbage collector explicitly had no issue with retain cycles and the team behind Microsoft's CLR expected to use automatic retain counts but then explicitly picked garbage collection partly because they could solve the problem of retain cycles (though probably more for performance reasons; you need an element of the tracing anyway to eliminate cycles so then you win by hugely simplifying assignment — see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/02/11/371015.aspx for a proper in depth evaluation of the many issues from the horse's mouth).

Comment: Just one more clarification, "NSAutoreleasePool" does work somewhat similar to Garbage collection right, if i'm not wrong?

Comment: @user1729070 Yes, somewhat.  Might I ask why you seem so intent on using garbage collection?

Comment: Also, why Xcode has an option called "Objective-C Garbage Collection"?

Comment: @user1729070 Garbage collection is still available, but deprecated, on OS X.

Comment: @zsnow, why because i am thinking for an alternate to avoid retain cycles issues if i use ARC.

Comment: Personally, I would very strongly suggest you use ARC.  The benefits far outweigh the downsides.  In the long run, ARC will make your life much easier.

Comment: "Garbage Collection is entirely unnecessary (for all practical purposes) when ARC is used." is a silly thing to say. In terms of abstraction/convenience, ARC is in-between manual memory management and full GC (perhaps nearer to GC). The annoyance of explicit strong/nullable-weak semantics becomes especially apparent when working with closures a lot, especially in ObjC where any ivar reference is an implicit strong `self` reference. I also have yet to see any credible, comprehensive comparison of ARC and well-engineered GC. Apple's opinion isn't enough.

Comment: Apple docs still say that [NSObject finalize] method available in iOS2 and later =) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/finalize

Comment: Beginning May 1, 2015, Mac App Store no longer accepts apps using gc.  https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=02202015a

Comment: All I can say, having lived for years with both .NET and ObjC is that garbage collection Makes Life Easier, and that Apple puts itself at a competitive disadvantage without it, in my opinion

Comment: As of macOS Sierra, programs that use Garbage Collection will no longer open.

Answer (score 11):

iOS does not have garbage collection

Comment: ... and never has, and never will. Garbage Collection is deprecated — http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW17

Comment: @Tommy - You mean the *Mac/OS X* implementation of garbage collection is deprecated.  Garbage Collection, as a concept, is still very much alive.

Comment: @aroth indeed; I explicitly mean "Apple explicitly prefers ARC to garbage collection so will not be implementing the latter on iOS and don't even want you using what they had implemented on the Mac".

Comment: Apple docs still say that [NSObject finalize] method available in iOS2 and later =) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/finalize